# i want to make 1 row multi item bootstrap carousel to be in 2 row

Tags: bootstrap-4

hello i have bootstrap  multiitem carousel in 1 row

i want to make it in 2 row

blob:https://imgur.com/1068f548-a001-42ad-bf06-d8d2d52de8e0

see image please

i have tried editing bootstrap and theme css ..

i am using wordpress
theme using bootstrap and bootstrap using slick

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

i want to make slick in 2 row with one pagination for that 2 row

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing width of element with class 'slick-track' to its half whatever is calculated 
and it will work.
Though you have to modify using jQuery or some callback function that slick slider provides.
or you can create each slick item with two images and both images contains width of 100% so it will appear like as you want

Comment: can you simplify your question.? what actually you want make it in the image you shown.